# Как сделать вставку частями по 1000 записей?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть таблица клиентов и в ней 60 млн. записей. Необходимо часть из них вставить в другую таблицу.

- таблица клиентов:

  ```
  CLIENTS (UUID RAW(255), NAME VARCHAR2, CREATED DATE)
  ```
- таблица, в которую нужно вставить записи из `clients`:

  ```
  CLIENTS_NEW (UUID RAW(255))
  ```

```
INSERT INTO CLIENTS_NEW (
    SELECT C.UUID FROM CLIENTS
    WHERE CREATED >= TO_DATE('01-01-2020', 'DD-MM-RRRR')
)
```

Данный запрос займет 6 часов. Поэтому, хочу поделить, чтобы обрабатывало частями по 1000 записей.

Как можно сделать такой запрос, подскажите пожалуйста?

Comment: Ну так и формируйте WHERE таким образом, чтобы копировалась не большая куча записей, а небольшой чанк. Скажем, за период 1 час, а не всё сразу... потом следующий час... и так далее.

Comment: @Akina а можно это сделать как-то так, что бы за один клик? например луп который будет инсерт делить построчно?

Comment: Делайте, кто мешает... организуйте цикл, создайте переменные, в которых будете хранить границы диапазона и которые будете на каждом витке пересчитывать...

Comment: у вас есть индекс по полю `CREATED` ?

Comment: `explain plan` и посмотрите что там тормозит, скорее всего отстутствие индекса по полю `created`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте индекс на колонку, по которой фильтруете записи для копирования:

```
create index idx_clients_created on clients (created)
/
```

Скорее всего, теперь делить вставку на блоки не понадобится. Но если вдруг, то:

```
insert /*+ append */ into clients_new (UUID) 
    select UUID from clients co
    where created >= date'2020-01-01'
    and not exists (
        select 1 from clients_new cn
        where cn.UUID = co.UUID) 
    fetch first 1000 rows only
/

1,000 rows inserted.
```